# delete all but two sorted items postgresql

Tags: postgresql

In my structure I have the following, I would like to keep (yellow) the most recent dates and delete the remaining? I don't necessary know the most recent date (ie 17/4/2021 and 10/2/2021 in my example) for each stock_id but I know I want to keep only the two most recent items.

Is that possible?

Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: this assumes that dates do not repeat within each `stock_id` group in your table, so top two dates are always unique.

You can assign rank to each row within `stock_id` after ordering by date and delete rows where rank is greater than 2.

```
DELETE FROM mytable
WHERE (stock_id, date) NOT IN (
    SELECT
        stock_id,
        date
    FROM (
        SELECT
            stock_id,
            date,
            row_number() over (partition by stock_id order by date desc) as rank
        FROM mytable
    ) ranks
    WHERE rank <= 2
)
```